# CPU clock scales down so computer is unusable after switching to battery

Tags: windows-7, laptop, cpu, power-management

When I am plugged in my laptop runs great however when I unplug it and I'm on battery power my CPU clock speed scales down pretty much all the way.

I know this is happening by monitoring the clock speed. When plugged in it will usually stay between 1000MHz and 3000MHz but when I unplug it it quickly scales down to less than 500MHz and will get as low as 100MHz and it will NEVER scale up at all on battery power. After I plug the power back in it will then begin operating normally in about a minute.

I have tried setting the MIN and MAX CPU performance in power options to 100% and have tried messing around with cooling settings which seemed to be a problem with HP laptops. I have a Toshiba Satellite M500-ST6444 running Windows 7.  The BIOS is up to date.  I have tried two versions.

Comment: a toshiba what? running windows what?

Comment: @CarlB - Why would the version of Windows matter in a case like this?  Besides...the author indicates what version he is using.  I really wish people could be voted down for idiotic comments.

Comment: @Ramhound - you can flag it as unconstructive if you like.Be nice.


Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you. We’re all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.

Comment: The problem is not that it scales down.(which is good), but that it never scales back up again. This can have many causes, one of which is broken ACPI tables. These are part of the BIOS. It is worth checking if there is a new BIOS version for your laptop and reading the changed notes.

Comment: @CarlB It is a Toshiba Satellite M500 running Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: @Hennes I previously updated my bios from 1.7 to 1.9 with no noticeable changes. I didn't see anything in the change logs referencing what you were suggesting.

Comment: I guess the next step is using a liveCD with a different OS to test if it is a win7software issue.

Comment: Yeah using a liveCD or just playing around with different Win installs on a spare HD is likely what I will do next when I have time.  I keep thinking it may be something with the Toshiba software and how it works with normal Win7 power management.  I've been disabling services and such with no luck.

Comment: In the power plans, are you sure you edited the battery plan?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps below:

- Go to Control Panel
- Select Power Options
- Click Change Advanced Settings
- Scroll down to Processor Power Management
- See if the minimum and maximum are 5% and 100% respectively

You can do this for all Power plans on your computer.